# How should I incorporate State N as a weight variable?

Tags: linear-regression, spss, weighted

My data structure is:

```
State           N           Var1            Var2
Alabama         23          54              42
Alaska          4           53              53
Arizona         53          75              65
```

`Var1` and `Var2` are aggregated percentage values at the state level. `N` is the number of participants in each state. I would like to run a linear regression between `Var1` and `Var2` with the consideration of `N` as weight, what is the best way to do it in SPSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `WEIGHT BY` or use a subcommand on `REGRESSION` - examples below.

```
DATA LIST FREE / State (A15) N  Var1  Var2 (3F2.0).
BEGIN DATA
Alabama         23          54              42
Alaska          4           53              53
Arizona         53          75              65
END DATA.

WEIGHT BY N.
REGRESSION
  /MISSING LISTWISE
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA
  /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10)
  /NOORIGIN 
  /DEPENDENT Var1
  /METHOD=ENTER Var2.

*Or using subcommand.
WEIGHT OFF.    
REGRESSION
  /MISSING LISTWISE
  /REGWGT=N
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA
  /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10)
  /NOORIGIN 
  /DEPENDENT Var1
  /METHOD=ENTER Var2.
```

You can see for yourself that these two procedures produce the same estimates. And that if you run the regression without weighting or using the `REGWGT` subcommand it will result in different estimates for this example.

Comment: Thanks, but when I added the weight in the analysis, most become statistically significant (p<0.05), but the relationship was in an opposite (than expected) direction. Is the weighted always more preferable than non-weighted in ecological study (like the one I am studying)?

Comment: I presumed your weights indicated repeated measurements - frequency weights. To see why the relationship changed you could make a scatterplot where the point is sized according to the weight.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for using the N as a weight?  If you do want to do that, since regression considers the weight to be a replication weight, you need to be careful about your degrees of freedom.

Comment: N represents the number of tweets coming from that state, it may or may not have replicate users and it may or may not have replicate tweets, but I thought it is a good idea to view states differently as to weight it based on the amount of information is available for the aggregated measures. Do you recommend not to use weight in this light, if so could you please let me know why?

Comment: Instead of using it as the weight variable, specify it as a weight in the regression procedure itself.

Comment: Yes, REGWGT is what I was referring to.